# Recording script with LoadRunner

Tags: html, c, testing, web, loadrunner

I'm trying to record a script with LoadRunner but nothing happens... 
I'll try to be more specific: I create a new web-based script (Web - HTTP/HTML) because I want to record actions taken into IE. 
I start doing things in IE and then stop the recording. 
What I expect is to find into "Action" the code that describes what I've just done in IE but nothing appears: "Action"contains only the return.

Any idea about what could be the issue?!

EDIT: I'm not recording any HTTPS action...

Answer (score 0):

Have you engaged in any activity in IE which connects to a server across the HTTP protocol, submitting requests and pulling responses?  if not, then you should not expect to see anything recorded.

There are also all sorts of permutations of 64 bit IE, of specific release numbers, versus your 32 bit recording engine of LoadRunner and specific release numbers, plus your credentials and any conflicts from antagonistic antivirus that could come into play.

The sample applications are your control set, such as the sample flights reservation system.  If you cannot record against that site with your version of LoadRunner then you have a conflict in one of the following

- Failed Installation
- Wrong Credentials
- Conflicting Antivirus (disable for testing)
- version conflicts (see requirements for your version of LoadRunner)
- 64 bit IE and 32 bit VUGEN (see proxy model for recording)

Answer (score 0):

You may try [local proxy recording](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-LoadRunner-and-Performance/Using-proxy-recording-for-local-AUTs-in-LoadRunner-12-00/ba-p/6416362#.VW1YekYyhT8).